# C# marshaling non-ASCII string?

Tags: c#, string, struct, ascii, marshalling

I'm developing an online game which has to trade packets with a C++ server. I'm doing it using the Unity 5 engine. My life was getting hard when I started to write the packet structures in the C# code using Marshaling. Unity have serious bugs here, but ok for all of the Unity related bugs I'm used to implement any sort of workaround, but this bug I'm facing right now I think it could be some Marshal's limitation.

I have this C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MSG_SendNotice : IGamePacket
{
    public const PacketFlag Opcode = (PacketFlag)1 | PacketFlag.Game2Client;

    private PacketHeader m_Header;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 96)]
    public string Text;

    public PacketHeader Header { get { return m_Header; } }
}
```

It should works fine when calling Marshal.PtrToStructure. The problem is when some non-ascii character is sent on Text. The Marshal fails the conversion and assign null to Text. If I manually change this non-ascii character to any ascii character before converting the packet buffer the marshal works. The point is that I canno't format all the packets server-side to avoid send these non-ascii characters, I actually need them to display the correct string. Is there a way to set the encoding of this marshaled string (Text) in its definition?

A ny ideas are appreciated, thanks very much.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you mean with _non-ascii characters_? Is it 8 bit characters >= 128 that can be represented in the current code page (like accented latin letters) or is it general UNICODE characters (like mathematical symbols and Korean letters)?

Comment: You are *defining* that the character-set is `Ansi`; I'm not sure what you *expect* to happen in the case of non-ASCII characters...

Comment: @MartinLiversage sorry for the mess. This "non-ascii" character is an 8-bit but it is >= 128 (this precisely character have the value of 0xE3). Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't possible, an Ansi string can use all 256 possible codes and 0xE3 is not special.  Usually translated to `ã`, depends on where you live.  Getting a null is entirely too strange, you'd need to get an exception for that to happen.  Whatever the real problem might be, you are not close to diagnosing it yet.  Do keep in mind that CharSet.Ansi is never correct, web servers don't speak your system locale, you need byte[] and use the correct Encoding.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for your comment. So, should I consider this probably being another Unity-related bug? Oh boy, I'm so tired of them :( Sometimes I have heavy thoughts of use SDL2 instead of Unity hehe. =[

Answer (score 0):

I would encode/decode the string manually:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 96)]
public byte[] m_Text;

public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return m_Text != null ? Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m_Text).TrimEnd('\0') : string.Empty;
    }

    set
    {
        m_Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value ?? string.Empty);
        Array.Resize(ref m_Text, 96);
        m_Text[95] = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that on set I'm manually adding a final 0 terminator (`m_Text[95] = 0`) to be sure the string will be a correctly-terminated C string.

I've done a test: it works even in the case that `m_Text` is null.